# How do I edit the Gui name of an existing AutoHotkey script?

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I came across a great little OSD volume script that I would like to incorporate into a larger script I'm working on. Unfortunately, I am running into issue with this script's Gui needing named different than what will be the parent. I thought it would be as simple as putting this as seen in documentation at the start of the volume section...

```
Gui, New 
Gui, VOL:New
```

and just changing all the "Gui, " to something like "Gui VOL:"
When I do get something to successfully work, it brings up the Gui when hovering over the taskbar and shows the volume level, but I am unable to change the volume at this point. Posted below is the working version of the volume script. If there is something else that needs modified I'm not seeing it and would love to be pointed in the right direction. -Thank You!!

```
; SOURCE: https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/94813-just-another-volume-osd/
#SingleInstance, Force
SetBatchLines, -1

; ▏════════════ User Variables ( Change as needed ) ════════════▏ 

Gui_W                := A_ScreenWidth / 2 - 500
Gui_X                := A_ScreenWidth - gui_W - 16
Gui_Y                := A_ScreenHeight - 120
; ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ 
Back_Color            := 0x000000
Font_Color            := 0x4499FF
BackBar_Color        := 0x000000
Bar_Color            := 0x005AC7
RoundedGui            := 3
; ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ 
VolUp_Key            := "^!=" 
VolDown_Key            := "^!-"
muteKey             := "^!0"    
Amount                := 1
; ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ 
Update_Freq            := 1
Timeout                := 1500
Max_Trans            := 200
; ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ 
mouseOverTray         := 1

; ▏════════════ End of user variables ════════════▏ 

Gui_X                := Gui_X ? "x" Gui_X : ""
Gui_Y                 := Gui_Y ? "y" Gui_Y : ""
Update                 := 0

SoundGet, Vol
Curr_Vol            := Vol
Trans                 := 0
Control_W            := GUI_W - 30

; ▏════════════ Volume GUI ════════════▏ 
Gui, Color, % Back_Color, 
Gui, Font, c%Font_Color% s10 Bold
Gui, Add, Text, w%Control_W% Center, Volume
Gui, Font
Gui, Add, Progress, w%Control_W% vProgress c%Bar_Color% +Background%BackBar_Color%, % Curr_Vol
Gui, Font, c%Font_Color% s12 Bold
SoundGet, Vol
Gui, Add, Text, w%Control_W% Center vVol, % Floor( vol ) "%"
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +E0x20 -SysMenu +ToolWindow
Gui, Show, NoActivate h80 w%Gui_W% %Gui_X% %Gui_Y% , Vol_OSD
; +AlwaysOnTop 
If ( RoundedGui )
    WinSet, Region, w%Gui_W% h100 R10-10 0-0, Vol_OSD
WinSet, Transparent, %Trans%, Vol_OSD

; ▏════════════ Sets the Hotkeys ════════════▏ 
Hotkey, % VolUp_Key, Volume_Up
Hotkey, % VolDown_Key, Volume_Down
Hotkey, % muteKey, Volume_Mute
SetTimer, Update, % Update_Freq
SetTimer, Fade, % "-" Timeout
Return

; ▏════════════ GUI fadeout ════════════▏ 
Fade: 
    While ( Trans > 0 && Update = 0)
    {    Trans -= A_Index / 4
        WinSet, Transparent, % Trans, Vol_OSD
        Sleep, 5
    } 
Return

; ▏════════════ Update ════════════▏ 
Update: 
    SetTimer, Update, % Update_Freq
    Update                := 0
    SoundGet, Vol
    If ( Vol <> Curr_Vol || forceUpdate = 1)
    {    Update             := 1
        GuiControl,, Progress, % Ceil( Vol )
        GuiControl,, Vol, % Ceil( Vol) "%"
        Curr_Vol         := Vol
        While ( Trans < Max_Trans )
        {    Trans         += A_Index * 2
            WinSet, Transparent, % Trans, Vol_OSD 
            Sleep 1
        } 
        SetTimer, Fade, % "-" Timeout
        forceUpdate             := 0
    } 
Return

; ▏════════════ Volume Down ════════════▏ 
Volume_Down:
    SoundSet, -%Amount%, MASTER
    SetTimer, Update, -1
Return

; ▏════════════ Volume Up ════════════▏ 
Volume_Up:
    SoundSet, +%Amount%, MASTER
    SetTimer, Update, -1
Return

; ▏════════════ Volume Mute ════════════▏ 
Volume_Mute:
    Send, {Volume_Mute}
    SoundGet, isMuted, MASTER, MUTE
    Gui, Font
    If ( isMuted = "On" )
        Gui, Font, cRed Italic s24
    else
        Gui, Font, c%Font_Color% s24 Bold
        GuiControl, Font, Vol
    forceUpdate             := 1
Return

#If ( mouseOverTray = 1 && overTray() )
; ▏════════════ Wheel down ════════════▏ 
WheelDown::    
    SoundSet, -%Amount%, MASTER
    SetTimer, Update, -1
Return

; ▏════════════ Wheel up ════════════▏ 
WheelUp::
    SoundSet, +%Amount%, MASTER
    SetTimer, Update, -1
Return
#If 

; ▏════════════ overTray Function  ════════════▏ 
overTray()
{    MouseGetPos, mX, mY, mWin
    WinGetClass, wClass, ahk_id %mWin%
    Return % wClass = "Shell_TrayWnd" ? 1 : 0
}

RETURN
^Home::  
        Reload
    Return
^Esc::  
        ExitApp
    Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GuiControl](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/GuiControl.htm#Remarks) says:

> To operate upon a window other than the default, include its name or
> number (or in [v1.1.03+] its HWND) followed by a colon in front of the
> sub-command as in these examples:
>
> ```
> GuiControl, MyGui:Show, MyButton
> GuiControl, MyGui:, MyListBox, Item1|Item2
> ```

```
; SOURCE: https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/94813-just-another-volume-osd/
#SingleInstance, Force
SetBatchLines, -1

; ▏════════════ User Variables ( Change as needed ) ════════════▏ 

Gui_W                := A_ScreenWidth / 2 - 500
Gui_X                := A_ScreenWidth - gui_W - 16
Gui_Y                := A_ScreenHeight - 120
; ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ 
Back_Color            := 0x000000
Font_Color            := 0x4499FF
BackBar_Color        := 0x000000
Bar_Color            := 0x005AC7
RoundedGui            := 3
; ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ 
VolUp_Key            := "^!=" 
VolDown_Key            := "^!-"
muteKey             := "^!0"    
Amount                := 1
; ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ 
Update_Freq            := 1
Timeout                := 1500
Max_Trans            := 200
; ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ 
mouseOverTray         := 1

; ▏════════════ End of user variables ════════════▏ 

Gui_X                := Gui_X ? "x" Gui_X : ""
Gui_Y                 := Gui_Y ? "y" Gui_Y : ""
Update                 := 0

SoundGet, Vol
Curr_Vol            := Vol
Trans                 := 0
Control_W            := GUI_W - 30

; ▏════════════ Volume GUI ════════════▏ 
Gui,VOL: Color, % Back_Color, 
Gui,VOL: Font, c%Font_Color% s10 Bold
Gui,VOL: Add, Text, w%Control_W% Center, Volume
Gui,VOL: Font
Gui,VOL: Add, Progress, w%Control_W% vProgress c%Bar_Color% +Background%BackBar_Color%, % Curr_Vol
Gui,VOL: Font, c%Font_Color% s12 Bold
SoundGet, Vol
Gui,VOL: Add, Text, w%Control_W% Center vVol, % Floor( vol ) "%"
Gui,VOL: +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +E0x20 -SysMenu +ToolWindow
Gui,VOL: Show, NoActivate h80 w%Gui_W% %Gui_X% %Gui_Y% , Vol_OSD
; +AlwaysOnTop 
If ( RoundedGui )
    WinSet, Region, w%Gui_W% h100 R10-10 0-0, Vol_OSD
WinSet, Transparent, %Trans%, Vol_OSD

; ▏════════════ Sets the Hotkeys ════════════▏ 
Hotkey, % VolUp_Key, Volume_Up
Hotkey, % VolDown_Key, Volume_Down
Hotkey, % muteKey, Volume_Mute
SetTimer, Update, % Update_Freq
SetTimer, Fade, % "-" Timeout
Return

; ▏════════════ GUI fadeout ════════════▏ 
Fade: 
    While ( Trans > 0 && Update = 0)
    {    Trans -= A_Index / 4
        WinSet, Transparent, % Trans, Vol_OSD
        Sleep, 5
    } 
Return

; ▏════════════ Update ════════════▏ 
Update: 
    SetTimer, Update, % Update_Freq
    Update                := 0
    SoundGet, Vol
    If ( Vol <> Curr_Vol || forceUpdate = 1)
    {    Update             := 1
        GuiControl,VOL:, Progress, % Ceil( Vol )
        GuiControl,VOL:, Vol, % Ceil( Vol) "%"
        Curr_Vol         := Vol
        While ( Trans < Max_Trans )
        {    Trans         += A_Index * 2
            WinSet, Transparent, % Trans, Vol_OSD 
            Sleep 1
        } 
        SetTimer, Fade, % "-" Timeout
        forceUpdate             := 0
    } 
Return

; ▏════════════ Volume Down ════════════▏ 
Volume_Down:
    SoundSet, -%Amount%, MASTER
    SetTimer, Update, -1
Return

; ▏════════════ Volume Up ════════════▏ 
Volume_Up:
    SoundSet, +%Amount%, MASTER
    SetTimer, Update, -1
Return

; ▏════════════ Volume Mute ════════════▏ 
Volume_Mute:
    Send, {Volume_Mute}
    SoundGet, isMuted, MASTER, MUTE
    Gui,VOL: Font
    If ( isMuted = "On" )
        Gui,VOL: Font, cRed Italic s24
    else
        Gui,VOL: Font, c%Font_Color% s24 Bold
        GuiControl,VOL:, Font, Vol
    forceUpdate             := 1
Return

#If ( mouseOverTray = 1 && overTray() )
; ▏════════════ Wheel down ════════════▏ 
WheelDown::    
    SoundSet, -%Amount%, MASTER
    SetTimer, Update, -1
Return

; ▏════════════ Wheel up ════════════▏ 
WheelUp::
    SoundSet, +%Amount%, MASTER
    SetTimer, Update, -1
Return
#If 

; ▏════════════ overTray Function  ════════════▏ 
overTray()
{    MouseGetPos, mX, mY, mWin
    WinGetClass, wClass, ahk_id %mWin%
    Return % wClass = "Shell_TrayWnd" ? 1 : 0
}
RETURN

^Home:: Reload

^Esc:: ExitApp
```

Comment: Thank you for this!! I completely missed anything about GuiControl and now I know! I hadn't even thought to look at that. I got an error about "Ceil( Vol )" being wrong, but thought it was trying to tell me the % signs were wrong. Time to do some reading. 
Thank you again!!